# MySQL: Using left join and union in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables named tblborrow and tblreturn wherein they both have date columns.

Now, what I am trying to do is to display almost all my columns from both tblborrow and tblreturn, in order by their date_borrowed and date_returned in union.

My tblborrow contains the following columns:

- borrow_id
- isbn
- member_id
- staff_id
- date_borrowed

While tblreturn contains:

- return_id
- borrow_id
- staff_id
- date_returned

I have done displaying them with left join using this:

```
SELECT a.isbn, a.member_id, a.staff_id, a.date_borrowed, b.staff_id, b.date_returned
FROM tblborrow AS a left join tblreturn AS b on a.borrow_id = b.borrow_id
ORDER BY date_borrowed, date_returned
```

It has given me what I need except the date_returned and date_borrowed are displayed in separate columns, of course.

Now I tried to use UNION on them by testing if it also gives me what I need and so I used:

```
SELECT date_borrowed FROM tblborrow
UNION ALL
SELECT date_returned FROM returning
```

And it has indeed. But I need these to be in one query only. I tried to simply combine the queries like this:

```
SELECT a.isbn, a.member_id, a.staff_id, b.staff_id,
(SELECT date_borrowed FROM tblborrow
UNION ALL
SELECT date_returned FROM returning)
FROM tblborrow AS a left join tblreturn AS b on a.borrow_id = b.borrow_id
ORDER BY date_borrowed, date_returned
```

But it says "Subquery returns more than 1 row" and I still can't seem to do it after lots of thorough Google-ing.

Help, anyone? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please edit your question to specify which columns and rows you need in your result set? Do you want one row per item, or one row per transaction? It seems likely that some items have been borrowed but not returned. What do you want in that case?  Other items have been borrowed and then returned. What do you want in that case? Do you want the date_returned value to be used in place of the date_borrowed value (for display and ordering) when a date_returned is available?

Comment: It was initially okay to have nulls on the remaining columns, but Gordon Linoff's query has already provided what I was asking for (and more, actually). Thanks anyway. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to separate rows for a borrow/return combination, then `union all` is appropriate.  If so, I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT b.isbn, b.member_id, b.staff_id, date_borrowed, 'borrow' as which
FROM tblborrow b
UNION ALL
SELECT b.isbn, b.member_id, r.staff_id, date_returned, 'return' as which
FROM tblreturn r join
     tblborrow b
     on r.borrw_id = b.borrow_id;
```

Comment: This did the trick! I haven't mentioned the part wherein how I would know if it was a "return" or "borrow" because I was planning a whole different (and hassle) thing, but you have solved both of my problems already. :)

Will study more about the strategy you used. Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this by adding a join on your union set

```
SELECT 
  a.isbn,
  a.member_id,
  a.staff_id,
  b.staff_id,
  u.combined_date 
FROM
  tblborrow AS a 
  LEFT JOIN tblreturn AS b 
    ON a.borrow_id = b.borrow_id 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      borrow_id,
      date_borrowed  AS combined_date
    FROM
      tblborrow 
    UNION
    ALL 
    SELECT 
      borrow_id,
      date_returned  AS combined_date
    FROM
      returning) u 
    ON (u.borrow_id = a.borrow_id) 
ORDER BY u.combined_date
```

Comment: This also did what I was asking for, except I would have posted a follow up question on how I would distinguish the borrow transactions from return transactions. It's fixed now, though. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. Because you are merging 2 different date values into the same column you will want to distinguish between which rows reflect a return vs. borrow action.

I am assuming that you want borrow/return date detail to be on every row. If you don't care about that then the last response by Gordon would be fine.

The first block below will show blanks for books borrowed but not returned.

Also UNION ALL will simply retain duplicate lines versus discarding them. The query below should function no differently if UNION ALL were used rather than UNION because it is not going to return any duplicates.

```
select          'BORROW'             as action
                , b.date_borrowed    as action_date
                , b.isbn
                , b.member_id
                , b.staff_id         as borrow_from_staff
                , b.date_borrowed
                , r.date_returned
                , r.staff_id         as return_to_staff
from             tblborrow b
      left join tblreturn r
             on b.borrow_id = r.borrow_id
union
select          'RETURN'             as action
                , r.date_returned    as action_date
                , b.isbn
                , b.member_id
                , b.staff_id         as borrow_from_staff
                , b.date_borrowed
                , r.date_returned
                , r.staff_id         as return_to_staff
from            tblreturn r
           join tblborrow b
             on r.borrow_id = b.borrow_id
order by        action_date
                , isbn
```